# React Native Android Layout Components Overlapping Issue

Tags: android, react-native

I have a simple view with dynamically created, vertically stacked buttons (mapped from an array), and set a static height and width to each button.  A view containing these buttons is generated from a function in the same component and called like so:

```
<View>
    {this.generateColumns(appButtons)}
</View>
```

Where appButtons is an array and generateColumns returns that view with vertically stacked buttons.  On iOS, this works perfectly, and I get vertically stacked buttons that scrolls if there are more buttons than room for them on the screen (I put the whole thing in a scroll view).  However, on android, the height of the view seems to be 0, as the 2 columns I generate in my render method overlap.

If I specify the height statically, by adding a `style={{height: 200}}` to the encapsulating view, then the overlapping does not occur, but the columns do not scroll when they overflow the screen, and obviously this only works if the arrays are a predetermined length.

Attached is two pictures to demonstrate this issue.  Both were generated using the same code.  I am using RN 0.41, and have updated my entire project recently.

Disclaimer: I have only run the app on the android emulator; I don't actually have a physical android device to test this on, but am working on obtaining one.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Android:
[image: Android]

iOS:
[image: iOS]